# Getting Autofac to inject the resolved type of an interface

Tags: entity-framework, generics, domain-driven-design, autofac

I am using Domain-Driven Design techniques with Entity Framework (EF) and some of my classes do not have public parameterless constructors. I have a service that works on a number of classes, some of which are Entity Framework and some are DTOs with public parameterless ctors.

I would therefore like Autofac to inject the resolved type of the interface into the service ctor and I handle the issues of creating/handling the resolved TInterface class myself, e.g.

```
class MyServiceClass<TInterface> : IMyServiceClass<TInterface>
{
    private Type _classType;

    public MyServiceClass(Type resolvedTypeOfTInterface)
    {
        _classType = resolvedTypeOfTInterface;
    }
}
```

When Autofac resolves `IMyServiceClass<TInterface>` it create a class of type `MyServiceClass<TInterface>`, which is fine. However also I want to find out the **type** of the class that the interface TInterface resolves to.

I can see how I could obtain the class by direct access to the Autofac via [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487262/resolve-type-without-creating-object) but that means using Autofac container directly, which does not sound like a very good idea.

Can anyone suggest a way of injecting the resolved type of the TInterface via some method/factory set up at container build time?

Comment: You'd have to configure the autofac container in your composition root. In that case, autofac will handle creating the class. You can't have autofac create the class and you yourself handling creating the class.

Comment: hi @Kenneth. I don't think my explanation was clear enough, so I have updated it. Basically I want the type, not an instance, of the TInterface type. I can't let Autofac create it as sometimes its constructor is private. My service code can check this and either create it using `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` if it has a public parameterless constructor or call extra code to handle the specialised factory for the given DDD class.

Comment: You could just ask for `typeof(TInterface)` inside the constructor, there's no need to inject that

Comment: Hi @Kenneth. I need to get the **resolved** type, e.g. if I supplied IMyClass interface it should resolve to the class that has this interface, which in this example might be MyClass. That is why I need a dependency injection framework! I'm sure this can be done, but I can't figure it out from the Autofac documentation.

Comment: If you execute typeof, it will get you the exact type of the current instance. If you supply an interface, the class can be used with any class that implements that interface, so there's nothing you can inject there, since it will still be usable by other classes that implement the same interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a number of approaches before I found a workable answer. The problem is that a generic class didn't seem allow some approaches, such as using Autofac's `ResolvedParameter`. My answer might not be the simplest way to do this, but it works. My solution is given below.

Firstly I changed MyServiceClass to add a method that can set the type:

```
class MyServiceClass <TInterface> : IMyServiceClass <TInterface>, ISetType
{
    private Type _classType;

    //normal ctor with any parameters it needs, but NOT including TInterface
    public MyServiceClass(...) {}

    public void SetType(Type resolvedType)
    {
        _classType = resolvedType;
    }
}
```

Then I added the following code to register the `MyServiceClass<>` type with Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (MyServiceClass<>))
    .As(typeof (IMyServiceClass<>))
    .OnActivating(e =>
    {
        var typeToLookup = e.Instance.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var foundEntry =
            e.Context.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(
               new TypedService(typeToLookup )).SingleOrDefault();
        ((ISetType)e.Instance).SetType(foundEntry.Activator.LimitType);
    });
```

This achieves what I need, i.e. if I have a constructor that has a parameter of type `MyServiceClass<IMyClass>` then after the `MyServiceClass<IMyClass>` is created by Autofac the private field `_classType` will contain the **resolved** class that IMyClass is attached to, which is what I want.

Any comments on how to do this in a better way would be gratefully received.