# Autofac resolve generic type with interface as a param

Tags: c#, generics, interface, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to register/resolve a generic type in Autofac which recieve a type param, which is an interface and already registered too.

I have the following:

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{

}

public partial interface IRepository<T>
    where T : IBaseEntity
{

}

public class NhRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : IBaseEntity
{

}

public interface IEntity : IBaseEntity
{

} 

public class Entity : IEntity
{

}
```

Registering:

```
//registering type    
builder.RegisterType<Entity>().As<IEntity>();

//registering generic type in Autofac
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NhRepository<>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerRequest();
```

Trying to resolve:

```
//the code below returns NhRepository<IEntity>().
_containerManager.Resolve<IRepository<IEntity>>();
```

I want a method to get `NhRepositoy<Entity>` instead `NhRepository<IEntity>()`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, most likely for the same sort of reason you had, i.e. because Entity Framework cannot work with interfaces. I solved it by using Autofac's `OnActivating` method [see documentation here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetime/events.html?highlight=onactivating) to find the type and then call a method inside the new instance to set the type.

Looking at the `OnActivating` documentation they show a case where you replace the instance with a new one, which is what you want. To create the new instance do this you need to do two things:

1. Resolve the IEntity to Entity class
2. Create the Generic class yourself.

The answer to the first one is in my [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118962/getting-autofac-to-inject-the-resolved-type-of-an-interface), so I won't repeat it here.

The second is fairly simple. You need to use the .NET `MakeGenericType` method to create the class, in your case the code would be something like.

```
e.ReplaceInstance(typeof(NhRepository<>).MakeGenericType( new []{resolvedType}));
```

where `resolvedType` is replaced by the command `foundEntry.Activator.LimitType` from my solution. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't work as you can't cast NhRepository<Entity> to IRepository<IEntity>, regardless of the classes implementing the respective interfaces.